# TypeScript > Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

i try to create functional component on React,  Typescript and ant ui. But when i create child component i have warning - "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?". Please tell me where i made mistakes?

CreateCounterpartyComponent:

```js
const CreateCounterpartyComponent: React.FC<FormComponentProps> = props => {
  const GET_ALL = gql`
    query {
      types {
        value: id
        name: full_name
      }
    }
  `;
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };
  const changeHandler = (e:number) => {
    console.log(e)
  }
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL);
  if (loading) return <Loader />;
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Item hasFeedback>
          {getFieldDecorator('address', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Address?' }],
          })(<CustomSeletor items={data.types} width="20%" changeEvent={(e)=>changeHandler(e)}/>)}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Send
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export const CreateCounterparty = Form.create()(CreateCounterpartyComponent);
```

CustomSeletor:

```js
const { Option } = Select;

interface IProps {
  items: ISelectorProps[];
  width: string;
  changeEvent(e:number):void;
}

export const CustomSeletor: React.FC<IProps> = ({ items, width, changeEvent }) => {
  const mystyles = {
    width: width,
  };
  const handleChange = (e:number) => {
      changeEvent(e)
  }
  const options = items.map(({ value, name }) => <Option key={value} value={value}>{name}</Option>);
  return (
    <Select style={mystyles} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code it's complaining about? I don't see any refs.

Comment: Yes, stack: Check the render method of `CreateCounterpartyComponent`.
    in CustomSeletor (at CreateCounterparty.tsx:115)
    in span (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)

Answer (score 2):

You're using antd. As specified on [this page](https://ant.design/components/form/):

Customized or third-party form controls can be used in Form, too. Controls must follow these conventions:

- It has a controlled property value or other name which is equal to the value of valuePropName.
- It has event onChange or an event which name is equal to the value of trigger.

  - Support ref:
  - Can only use class component before React@16.3.0.
  - Can use forwardRef to add ref support after React@16.3.0.

antd requires that `CustomSelector` be able to receive refs. Function components must be wrapped in `React.forwardRef` in order to receive refs, otherwise you will get the error you see.

The solution is to wrap `CustomSelector` in `forwardRef`:

```
export const CustomSelector = React.forwardRef(({ items, width, changeEvent }, ref) => {
  const mystyles = {
    width: width,
  };
  const handleChange = (e:number) => {
      changeEvent(e)
  }
  const options = items.map(({ value, name }) => <Option key={value} value={value}>{name}</Option>);
  return (
    <Select ref={ref} style={mystyles} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
});
```

You should ensure that `Select` conforms to the requirements of antd. Check their docs for that as I don't know them.

Comment: Select is a component of antd (import { Select } from 'antd'). And when i try to wrap CustomSelector in forwardRef i have error with props like a: Property 'items' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: Then I am unsure where your issue is. Consult the antd docs; this is definitely an issue to do with the integration of antd with your code and not to do with React/TypeScript